# Parse.com : issue with PFQuery and NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, nspredicate

This is my query :

```
//The column 'facebookId' has a String type
//The ACL for the table 'User' are set to Public Read
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "facebookId = '846810882066568'")
var query = PFQuery(className: "User", predicate: predicate)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
         if let objects = result {
              println(objects)
         }
    }
}
```

The row I am querying exists but the returned result in an empty array :

```
[]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is this a parse user or a custom user class?

Comment: The parse one to which I have added some columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User is a special class so you need to create the query with the special class memos rather than using the class name:

```
var query = PFUser.query()
```

Comment: Worked ! But in the result, I only get two fields : 'username' and 'facebookId'. How to get other fields ?

Comment: how do you verify that? I think you should get everything without having to use one of the `fetch` methods

Comment: `if let objects = result as? [PFUser] {
                            println(objects)
                            for object in objects {
                                if let profileName = object["profileName"] as? String {
                                    println(profileName)
                                }
                            }
                        }`

Comment: I see the object printed with only 2 fields. When I try to access the 'profileName' field, it prints nothing

Comment: Try fetching the object